Android studio emulator does not open
Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/kRaGUb8R.png)
i have tried reinstalling android studio, ive also updated .NET, ive wiped the data, ive tried other types of emulator hardwares, none of that seemed to work. please help

Please [edit] your question to replace the screenshot containing the log/error message with text, formatted as a [code block]. Please also describe why none of the other questions citing the error message don't help: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Emulator+terminated+with+exit+code+-1073741515%22
